# Descargar archivo generado con PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, google-colab

estoy ocupando pyspark con google colab y estoy trabajando con un .csv y le aplico varios filtros, y quiero descargar ese conjunto de datos como un nuevo csv.
¿Eso es posible?

Aqui mi codigo:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
prices = spark.read.options(header="true").csv("precios.csv")
prices.show()
```

se puede descargar "price"?, el ejemplo tal cual no se modifica nada, pero en lo que estoy haciendo si.

Comment: Esto te puede servir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394737/exporting-data-from-google-colab-to-local-machine

Comment: Hola, esa pregunta no, pero en relacionada me salió la siguiente que si me resolvió el problema, muchas gracias: https://stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/questions/31385363/how-to-export-a-table-dataframe-in-pyspark-to-csv?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=es&_x_tr_hl=es-419&_x_tr_pto=nui,sc